# Highcharts get flatted on full screen

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I have two screens...
Highcharts looks normal on the first one even on Full Screen or minimized.
On the second one it looks normal only if it's not in full screen...
This is how it looks:
[FullScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U91Mw.png)

And [minimized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9v2Jl.png)

How to set it to be normal on both screens in both mode?

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lxi6.png)

Comment: I don't know.. maybe your first chart has height 200px and the second one has 300px? ;) So you simple use different heights of charts - that is the reason.

Comment: @PawełFus Sorry, but I still missing, where is height 200px and were is 300px? :D

Comment: These charts: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U91Mw.png - 200px for each. These: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9v2Jl.png - 300px

Comment: @PawełFus Yeah, but still can't find it in code? :D

Comment: Sorry for a delay, I had some holidays ;) Anyway, I won't be able to help you with code, you shared only screenshots and **minified** code. Recreate issue in jsfiddle and we might be able to help you. PS: Check also CSS (media queries) :)